# CSS margin getting 'ignored' when I set the padding of the parent element to zero?

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a Terms of Use page using [Materialize.css](http://materializecss.com/), which is contained within a `card-panel`. I find that 'as-is', the spacing at the top is too much:

[image]

Here, the `margin-top` of the `h4` element get added to the `padding` of the containing `card-panel`, which is 24px. I think the former is actually sufficient spacing by itself from the top of the shadowed box, so I tried setting `padding-top` of this `card-panel` to zero using the following SCSS rule:

```
.lucy-terms {
  .card-panel.lucy-card-panel {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
```

However, with this enabled, I find that the spacing becomes too small:

[image]

When I highlight it, it seems like the `margin-top` of the `h4` element falls outside the box. Shouldn't the `margin` of the element fall within the containing element? How can I fix this?

I've included the relevant snippet below.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.card-panel.lucy-card-panel {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Materialize.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container lucy-terms">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m12">
          <div class="card-panel lucy-card-panel">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h4 class="center-align">Terms of Use</h4>
              <p class="flow-text uppercase">PLEASE NOTE THAT YOUR USE OF AND ACCESS TO OUR SERVICES (DEFINED BELOW) ARE SUBJECT TO THE FOLLOWING TERMS. IF YOU DO NOT AGREE TO ALL OF THE FOLLOWING, YOU MAY NOT USE OR ACCESS THE SERVICES IN ANY MANNER.</p>
              <p class="flow-text">Effective date: April 2, 2018</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like a normal case of [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

Comment: Indeed it looks like the 'parent and first child' case. How would I apply  clearance to separate the margin-top of the `card-panel` from the margin-top of its first child block (the `h4`)?

Comment: `.card-content { overflow: auto; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding `display: inline-block` to the parent element (the `card-panel`):

```
.lucy-terms {
  .card-panel.lucy-card-panel {
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove the margin from the top of the `h4`.

`.card-content h4 { margin-top: 0; }`

Comment: This would make the effective margin `24px`, the padding of `card-panel`, instead of the default margin of `h4`, which is not exactly what I want. (Also, if I change `h4` to `h5`, for example, I want the margin of the latter to apply).

Comment: I didn't understand your question to ask anything other than how to not have both the padding and the margin rendering. If you're concerned about styling the HTML tag specifically, then give the H4 a class then style off of that, and if you change it to a H5 later, it won't matter.